# Explicitly set Javascript files mimetype

Tags: javascript, postgresql, react-redux, loopbackjs, file-type

As I am pretty new to React, need help, please.

I have encountered a use case where the client is uploading a javascript file in the project but upload fails because different browsers see the same file in a different way (in terms of file type).

As per project guidelines, only 'application/javascript' files are allowed to get saved in the database. but when a user uploads a file from chrome it gives as 'text/javascript' and uploads fail.

now the client wants us to update the mime-type of javascript files, for example, if 'text/javascript' comes to the server rewrite the mime-type to 'application/javascript' and save the file.

**is it even possible to change a JS file mime-type ?**

if Yes, any help is really appreciated.
**What is the ideal way to solve this issue.**

**JS file, being supported in Database.**

```
[
  {
    "id": "aac491d22bcbb4a95deed88b738c1edc",
    "mimeType": "application/javascript",
    "extensions": [
      "js"
    ],
    "mediaTypeGroupId": "21f64da1e5792c8295b964d159a14491",
    "created": "2021-11-15T06:31:52.237Z",
    "updated": "2021-11-15T06:31:52.237Z",
    "self": "/mediatypes/aac491d22bcbb4a95deed88b738c1edc"
  }
]
```

**clients Wants us to do like this (just sample code, forgive idea)**

```
if (file.files[0].type === "text/javascript") {
    const newType = file.files[0].type;
    newType = "application/javascript";
    console.log("yes", file.files[0].type);
  }
```

**PS: Tech-Stack used is REACT, REDUX, LOOPBACK, POSTGRES.**
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can re-create the File object and override the type using the method below.

```
new File([file], file.name, {type: "application/javascript"});
```

For your example, you can use it like this, you'll see the only change will be the type.

```
if (file.files[i].type === "text/javascript") {
    file.files[i] = new File(file.files[i], file.files[i].name, {
        type: "application/javascript",
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you, @anotherglitchinthematri.
I will surely work on this. but is a good practice to change the type of file ?

Comment: @SameerHuilgolkar I strongly advocate against changing the type manually and even if the "application/javascript" type suggested since 2006, "text/javascript" is still valid, but this divergence is not the issue here, the validation of the user input is. Since both "text/javascript" and "application/javascript" types are valid, both mime types should be allowed to upload. You can use the workaround above, but that will be not the real solution for the problem, I suggest you to inform your client about allowing both mime-types.

Comment: Thanks @anotherglitchinthematrix, all noted. Even I stand on this. I will surely look into this.